# Why does Jessica Jones react differently to Kilgrave's powers?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, jessica-jones

Plainly speaking

> Jessica Jones is immune to Kilgrave's mind-control since the start of the series but she realizes it herself later

I have read Wikipedia on her & in the comics, this reaction to Kilgrave's powers is explained clearly. Jean Grey helps shield her mind.

So, does the same explanation hold true for for the TV series too? If not than why does Jessica react differently to Kilgrave's powers?

Answer (score 7):

I hope this would help :

A conversation between Jessica and Luke from episode 12 (~ the 6th minute)

> Jessica : when he made me... kill Reva... I didn't realize it at the
> time, but I think it severed the hold he had on me. He can't control
> me. Not anymore.
>
> Luke : You're free of him... because of Reva?
>
> Jessica : Maybe.
>
> Luke : So, because you didn't want to kill her... you were able to
> push him out.

Comment: Thats... disturbing. It implies Jessica did everything else willingly, subconsciously anyway. Victim blaming much? WTH marvel.

Comment: I always thought that because she has been in his control for a longest time (out of all the other victims) she built an immunity to his virus. The killing of Reva just made her snap out of it. I think it's hinted by the end of the season when we see his power got less stronger (the range, duration) and they started to experiment.

Comment: @Zikato  He wasn't getting weaker though. He was just trying to be stronger to be able to control Jessica again and he succeeded (he controlled Luke for much more than 12 hours & and controlled most of the people in a large theatre) but I like your theory and it would've made more sense to me if the writers went with it

Comment: Everything Jessica did after that, she did for the fear of being controlled again, until the point she learnt that she couldn't be controlled anymore.

Answer (score 3):

> So, does the same explanation hold true for for the TV series too? If not than why does Jessica react differently to Kilgrave's powers?

No. Mutants don't exist in the Marvel Cinematic Universe due to licensing issues. Fox holds the rights to Mutants in Movies and TV, Marvel does not. So it can't be Jean Grey's help.

As to how it happened, it has not been explained yet.